# String handling in matlab

Tags: arrays, string, matlab

I am working on this code which is to copy the sentences stored in one array to another.
'text1' is the array which stores all my sentences and `C1` is the array into which the sentences have to be copied.

`text1` is a `1x8` array with `text1(1,1)` containing the first sentence, `text1(1,2)` with the second sentence and so on.
The following is the code that I have written to copy the contents from `text1` to `C1`:

```
for i=1:vr
        if(Track(i)<0)

            text1{1,i};
           C1(1,j)=text1(1,i)
            j=j+1;
        end
end
```

Can somebody help me?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't included examples of neither `text1`, `Track` nor `vr` I can't test anything. But your assigning `C1` incorrectly if its a cell array. Use `C1{1,i} = text{1,i}`instead.

But, if you want to copy everything in `text1` into a new cell array, with exactly the same contents `C1 = text1;` will do that.

Comment: thank you. Do you know any way I could assign a string, say text='I am greatful' to a cell, say C(1) ?

Comment: do `C{1} = 'I am grateful'`

Comment: You need to observe that there is a distinction between `C(1)` and `C{1}`.

Comment: If you use curly brackets `{}` you can have anything within one element of the cell array, or as it's told at Mathworks about cell arrays "Arrays that can contain data of varying types and sizes". But if you are using parenthesis, you will have the 'common' array type.

Comment: So, then please accept the answer. It's a green marker next to the arrows next to my answer. Then I will get some credit and people will continue to help you. @Geethu

Comment: I don't have 15+ reputation as of now so that I can vote up. I have only 9 points. Will sure vote up when I cross the minimum score :)

Comment: I don't mean vote up, I mean accept answer, it's just below vote up. @Geethu

Comment: My pleasure.Just having a hard time getting familiarised with the site.

Comment: No problem. If you look at the top of the page to the right, there is a help tab, which contains a 'tour'-link that perhaps could be helpful. @Geethu

Answer (score 1):

If `Track` is an array, you should be able to do it follows (using logical indexing):

```
C1 = text1(Track < 0);
```

Or something similar to that, depending on exact structure of your data.

Comment: @Geethu  Proivde example of your data, initialization, etc. Like this we can be guessing only what you have and what you don't have.

Answer (score 0):

Have you initialized the cell `C1` and `j`?

```
j = 1;
C1 = {};
for i=1:length(text1)
        if( Track(i)<0 )
            text1{1,i};
           C1(1,j)=text1(1,i)
            j=j+1;
        end
end
```

Comment: Yes I have initialised C1 and j. Track is an integer array based on whose values the copying is done.Still this is the output I get when I try to print the contents of C1:
C1 = 

    [1x150 char]    [1x150 char]

Comment: @Geethu Proivde example of your data, initilization, etc. Like this we can be guessing only what you have and what you don't have.

Comment: Is text1 a cell array? `C1` being `[1x150 char]` suggests that it is a cell in itself. Try the edit I made above.

Comment: @Sid , when I implement your code line 6 in your code is reported to be an error saying: "Conversion to cell from char is not possible."

Comment: So it's already a character array. You're just having some type mismatch errors here. What could help is to use class(var) to see what class each of your variables are and make sure you get them right.